# How do I read from a mpsc::channel for a specified amount of time without unstable features or external crates?

Tags: rust, timeout, channel

I'm trying to continuously read from a [`Receiver`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) for a specified duration. I've come up with the following solution

```
pub fn get<T>(
    rx: &Receiver<T>,
    get_duration: time::Duration,
) -> Result<(), Err> {
    let (dur_tx, dur_rx) = channel();
    let _ = thread::spawn(move || {
        // timer to kill receiving
        thread::sleep(get_duration);
        let _ = dur_tx.send("tick");
    });

    let mut time_to_break = false;
    while time_to_break == false {
        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(resp) => {
                //...
            }
            Err(_) => ()
        }
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1)); // avoid using cpu 100%
        let _ = dur_rx.try_recv().map(|_| time_to_break = true);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Is there a better way around this without unstable or deprecated features (e.g. [`select`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.select.html)) or external crates?

Comment: Can't you use [`recv_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout)?

Comment: Although, probably you want [`recv_deadline`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_deadline), which is still unstable..

Comment: I want to read all responses for a fixed duration (say a minute). Tbh my only problem is having to manually sleep to avoid overusage of cpu, something which in Go for example is handled with select and I guess the select! macro does something similar.

Comment: What is the purpose of *"without external crates"*? Rust is built around crates and recommends you to use other peoples work. I don't get why so many people think it's a bad thing :/

Comment: I think using an external crate for something that simple is unnecessary. Although I found most of these crates great, it does feel some times a bit like nodejs ending up with a million dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [`recv_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout), which should also be a lot neater:

```
pub fn get<T>(rx: &Receiver<T>, get_duration: Duration) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let start_time = Instant::now();
    loop {
        let now = Instant::now();
        if start_time + get_duration > now {
            let duration = start_time + get_duration - now;
            match rx.recv_timeout(duration) {
                Ok(resp) => {
                    // handle message
                }
                Err(RecvTimeoutError::Timeout) => break,
                Err(RecvTimeoutError::Disconnected) => {
                    // handle disconnect
                }
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

When [`recv_deadline`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_deadline) stabilises, you can make this even simpler because you will just calculate the deadline once and then keep passing it, instead of recomputing the new duration each iteration.

---

*Edit:* A case in point for why you should use `recv_deadline` when it becomes stable is a bug in the code I just gave you. `Duration` is always positive, but my original calculation did not check to prevent underflow, which would have caused an intermittent panic. I have updated it now to ensure that won't happen.

Here's what it would look like using deadlines (in Nightly Rust) instead:

```
#![feature(deadline_api)]

pub fn get<T>(rx: &Receiver<T>, get_duration: Duration) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let deadline = Instant::now() + get_duration;
    loop {
        match rx.recv_deadline(deadline) {
            Ok(resp) => {
                // handle message
            }
            Err(RecvTimeoutError::Timeout) => break,
            Err(RecvTimeoutError::Disconnected) => {
                // handle disconnect
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I wonder what does Rust internally use to not drain cpu usage?

Comment: You can check the source: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sync/mpsc/stream.rs#L191-L203